# device orientation values jumping around?

Tags: javascript, device-orientation

is it normal that the alpha, beta, and gamma value of deviceorientation event aren't continuous? ( except from passing from -90 to 90, or 0 to 360 )

take a look at this picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZfTc.png

when i roll my phone, at some point, the alpha ( yaw ) and and beta ( pitch ) value will "jump" to another value, while the gamma ( roll ) value will gradually go from -90 to 90

here's the project i'm currently working on to further demonstrate this : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ReRORG open this up on your phone, then roll your phone to the left slowly and at some point the colors will change abruptly

as you can see i'm displaying the alpha,beta and gamma values untouched here :

```
$("#yaw")[0].textContent = "yaw :" + event.alpha;
$("#pitch")[0].textContent = "pitch :" + event.beta;
$("#roll")[0].textContent = "roll :" + event.gamma;
```

why is that? is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: Maybe it's a limitation of your hardware sensor? Does it work when you use other apps/websites on your phone? Did you try a different phone on your code?

Comment: I've been trying to ask my friends to try it out, they all say it's working as I would've liked it to work but when I push them to do extreme tests like the one i described above, they encounter the same error. it's unclear whether my friends have tested the website thoroughly and i don't want to push them too much. beside, i only have one phone